# Select next 7 days using only day and month

Tags: mysql, date-arithmetic

I have a table with birthdays in them, formatted in YYYY-MM-DD. My aim is to return results if the birthday is within the next 7 days.

I need it to use only the month and day, because if it reads the year also, a birthday in 1993 is never going to be within the next 7 days. It also needs take month changes into consideration.

For example, if its the 28th of Feb, and a birthday in the table is on the 1st March, that would be within 7 days, but not within the same month.

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY, '%m-%d')
```

This is where i'm at, at the moment, but I know i'm miles off.

Comment: why not use date_add, then use between to get your values? `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE date BETWEEN date1 and date2` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to format both of your dates in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), '%m-%d')
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you! Will this work for month roll overs too?

Comment: you are comparing strings, it would work for roll over month but not at the end of the year (for example if now returns 27 december)

Answer (score 0):

retrieve current year with YEAR(CURDATE(), make a date biy concatenating with month and day coming from birthday and remove 7 days, check if curdate is in the range :

```
select *
from user 
where 
Curdate() between date_sub(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-',    date_format(birthday, '%m-%d')), interval 7 day) 
and CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-', date_format(birthday, '%m-%d')) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take year part from today's date and concatenate it with the month and day part of the dob column value. And cast that string to date. Then use that as a sub-query and check whether thet new column day difference is between 0 and 7.

**Query**

```
SELECT t.* -- select except the `new_col` 
FROM  (SELECT *, 
          CAST((Concat(YEAR(NOW()), '-', DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d'))) AS DATE 
          ) AS 
                `new_col` 
   FROM `user`)t 
WHERE DATEDIFF(t.`new_col`, NOW()) BETWEEN 0 AND 7;
```